# Оповещение администратора о новом пользователе. WordPress

Tags: авторизация, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Подскажите плагин для WP, который будет отсылать письмо на почту админа о новом пользователе.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел в сети, [как отключить такое оповещение](http://leksus.info/otklyuchenie-opoveshheniya-admina-wp-po-pochte-o-registracii-novogo-polzovatelya/). Т.е. вам надо, как я понимаю, проделать обратные действия, указанные в этой статье.

P.S. Вообще, эта опция по идее должна быть включена по умолчанию. Может вы просто не указали свой email (Параметры > Общие > Адрес e-mail)?  Там даже пояснение рядом стоит: "Этот адрес используется в целях администрирования. Например, для уведомления о новых пользователях."